# Can I not use “the” in my sentence?

Tags: definite-article

I have a sentence translated from Russian by Google:

> I will sand **the** walls and you will suck up **the** dust.

I don’t understand, can I not use “the” in this sentence?

Context: I have a photo from my work where I am standing near the vacuum cleaner which looks like R2-D2, a droid from Stars Wars. I made a 4 picture comic where the last picture is my photo. My question is about pic 2.

Pic 1. Luke Skywalker and R2-D2 are standing near the wrecked ship. Luke says:

> Galactic flip-flops! We're stuck here forever!

Pic 2. Luke says R2-D2:

> Not enough money for repairs. R2-D2, I got us a job at the interplanetary exhibition centre. I will sand **the** walls and you will suck up **the** dust.

Pic 3. R2-D2 says:

> *Chirping:*
> Why the ship was wrecked by you but to suck is have to by me?!

(Have no idea, is it right or not, but it’s the only way I could translate my Russian sentence)

Pic 4. My photo with the vacuum cleaner.

> A little more, R2-D2. We'll earn money for the ship and get off this planet.

Can you explain why are there 2 articles “the”? I don’t want to say about some definite walls and dust. I want to say about a type of work which I will be doing. For example: At work I build walls. Google translates this sentence without “the”. The other example with dust: Vacuum cleaner sucks up dust. There are no these articles.

How will my sentence sound without the articles for a native speaker?

Comment: _The walls_ implies _the walls of the exhibition centre_ (where you will be working). It would be OK to say "I will sand walls" if you mean 'any walls'. Similarly, I assume _the dust_ refers to the dust that will be generated by your sanding work. "You will suck up dust" would mean 'dust in general'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to "explain" syntactic choices made by Google Translate, which means ***we can't ask the speaker / writer for more context***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rather odd.

"Sand the walls" would mean "to rub sandpaper on the walls of the exhibition centre (to make them smooth)".  That seems odd, since "sanding walls" is not something that people do.  The definite article says I should know which walls - and I think I do!  "The walls of the exhibition centre"

Now I know that sanding creates dust, so I would infer that *the* dust is "the dust that is created by sanding the walls"  The definite article implies that I should know which dust, and the context provides a potential source of dust. Putting two-and-two together, I can make this inference.

If you don't use "the dust", it would presumably mean "any dust in the exhibition centre".  That might be better. But it doesn't explain why anyone would be using sandpaper on the walls.

Comment: The grammar is worse in the other captions, especially "is have to by me"  That is completely ungrammatical.